# Driving 4W Tube Lamp with 900mA LED Driver

Tags: led-driver, fluorescent-lamp

Can i use an LED driver circuit ([like this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10W-DC-12V-24V-LED-Constant-Current-Driver-Power-900mA-High-Power-Led-Hot-Sell/32838117864.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.158.qAKJNO&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10345_10342_10325_10343_10546_10340_10341_10548_10541_10562_10084_10083_10307_10175_10060_10155_10154_10539_10312_10059_10313_10314_10534_10533_100031_10103_10073_10594_10557_10596_10595_10142_10107,searchweb201603_25,ppcSwitch_7&btsid=ffd09c34-1ed6-48ae-ad02-ad663b2adcaf&algo_expid=cdd62f65-98e8-4f5a-ad7f-aae42cf122f6-20&algo_pvid=cdd62f65-98e8-4f5a-ad7f-aae42cf122f6&rmStoreLevelAB=0)) to power a 4W fluorescent lamp ([like this](http://datasheet.octopart.com/F4T5-BLB-EIKO-datasheet-62071438.pdf)) from a DC power source?

> **Voltage = 4.44V**   |   *4W = Voltage X 900mA*

While i hope to use 3 AAA batteries (4.5V), USB power bank (5V) or 12V battery, i am suspicious about this scheme.

Comment: -1 for expecting us to follow two links just to get enough information to understand the question. You should summarise the essential details of the datasheets in your question. StackExchange policy is that each question should stand on its own even if the links die. See the Help link below.

Comment: @Transistor really eh. Mind you, answer does not need the links, LED driver and fluorescent lamp do not go in the same sentence ;)

Comment: Cool edit. question went from something curt to something meaningless. We can not read minds... Correct to use 3AAA batteries for what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UM NO.

LED drivers are constant current sources which is what LED's need.

Fluorescent lamps are something different entirely and need high voltages and small currents to "excite" them.

**ADDITION** *(Since you changed the question. Please don't do that here, it makes the existing answers weird.)*

No you can not run that LED driver with 4.5V, or 5V. Data sheet says it needs 12-24V input. You will need at least 1A available from the 12V. Depending on the efficiency of the driver maybe even 1.25A.